# Only show once adview

Tags: java, android, loops

I current code keep on showing my ads whenever it gets reloaded. how do I keep it from only showing the ads once. I am an extreme noob so I try to implement an if then statement but it doesn't seem to work. any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated. Goal is to only show the ads once.

```
int loaded=1;
public static void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded() && loaded==1) {
        interstitial.show();
        int loaded=2;
    }
    setAd();
}
```

Comment: `int loaded=2;` -> `loaded=2;`.

Comment: @saka1029 why not submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
int loaded=2;
```

creates a new int called loaded scoped to the function. The integer being checked by the function is always 1.

Delete the word int from this line and change the declaration of int loaded to be

```
static int loaded = 1;
```